# Get the type of object that called a registered function in QTP

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I'm trying to develop a generic registered function that verifies the existence of a given object, then adds a line to the report to say whether it was found or not.

Here's the function:

```
'@Description Reports in the test results whether the given object exists.
Public Function verifyExistence(ByRef test_object)
    If test_object.Exist(1) Then
        Reporter.ReportEvent micPass, "Verify that the page exists.", "Page exists."
    Else
        Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "Verify that the page exists.", "Page does not exist."
    End If
End Function
RegisterUserFunc "Page", "verifyExistence", "verifyExistence"
```

This works fine for Page objects, but how can I 'genericize' this so it can be used with any object type?  I realize I'll need to add a RegisterUserFunc line for each object type.

Ideally, I'd have a line that looks like this:

```
typename = getType(test_object)
if typeName = "Page" Then
    objName = test_object.GetROProperty("title")
    ... 'and so on.
end if
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `test_object.GetTOProperty("micclass")` for the test object's name. 
Some dynamic objects (e.g. those returned from `ChildObjects`) may not have this property set on QTP's side in which case you should do `test_object.GetROProperty("micclass")`.

The **RO** method should always work but its a bit slower than the **TO** method which should *almost* always work.

Answer (score 0):

The TypeName() function should return (nearly) the type name of the object, e.g. "IRegExp2" for a RegExp.